# Using 'where' in Sequelize Many-to-Many query

Tags: sequelize.js

Just started using sequelize, how and 'where' do you use where to specify condition on a table? I have the belongstomany relationship defined like this:

```
db.users.belongsToMany(db.groups, {through: "users_groups", foreignKey:"user_id"});
db.groups.belongsToMany(db.users, {through: "users_groups",foreignKey:"group_id"});
```

1) I want to be able to be able to see if a user is in a group given a user id

2) I want to retrieve all groups and the groups info attended by a user given a user id

where do I put the "where" in these cases?

I tried

```
Group.findOne({
 through: {where:{id:req.body.group_id}},
 include: [{
  model: User,
  through:{
    where:{id:req.body.user_id}
  }
 }]
}).then(data=>{
 res.send(data);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`through` property expects a junction model or an alias, you are giving it a where caluse.

```
const { group_id: groupId, user_id: userId } = req.body;

Group.findOne({
     where: { id: groupId },
     include: [{
      model: User,
      through: 'users_groups',
      where: { id: userId },
     }]
    }).then(data=>{
     res.send(data);
    })
```

For more information [read here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html)

Comment: It worked thank you!! can you also help me out with creating and deleting from the auto generated joint table? apparently you can't just use create() to insert into it directly